# Skipping the staging area using Git Source Control Provider

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

Is there a direct equivalent of 'git commit -a -m ' while using the Git Source Control Provider

I use Git Source Control Provider Version 1.1 with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

No, not from the current state of the commit implementation, like [`GitUI.UI.CommitBox.xaml.cs`](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GitUI/UI/CommitBox.xaml.cs) illustrates.

Plus you see issues like "["No file has been staged for commit" error when committing from the Git Pending Changes window](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/workitem/17803)", which shows the commit dialog still need some work.
So it is a good opportunity to contribute to that project.